# Confused by the grammar

Tags: grammar

The sentence that confuses me:

It has taken so long for historians to focus on the civil law of early modern England.

At first, I thought it means that **historians have been focused on the civil law for a excessive long period**. After checking the translation in my first language, I was surprised that it actually means that **there is an excessive long period before the historians start to focus on the civil law**. That's quite counter-intuitive to me. Could anyone explain the mechanism behind this? Also, how will you say in English my wrong perception?

Comment: What you expected is: Historians have focused on the civil law of early modern England for too long.

Comment: The important thing is that "so" is a degree modifier of "long". It can be paraphrased as _It has taken a (very) long time for historians to focus on the civil law of early modern England_.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I would have thought it meant "historians haven't focused on the civil law of early modern English until now, and they took too long to do it."

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Yes, well rephrased. I was answering question #2, "How will you say in English my wrong perception?" The OP wants to hear how to express what she thought the sentence was saying.

Comment: @YosefBaskin ah, my mistake.

Comment: An issue here is that the "sentence" as given is not a sentence, or at least not an idiomatic one. It needs something else, like "We are surprised that it has taken so long..." or "It has taken so long... that all evidence there actually **was** law has disappeared completely."

Comment: The OP's confusion seems to have more to do with the meaning of *focus* than with the meaning of *taken so long*. The author intended the verb *to focus* to mean something like 'to bring into focus', while the OP interpreted it as 'to keep in focus'.

Answer (score -1):

How it works: "has taken so long for..." describes an action that has taken a long time to begin. The action has been delayed for the period of time; the action itself is what comes after the **for**. Does that help?

Comment: There is no action that comes after *for* here; in the sentence that the question is about *for* is followed by *historians*.